# Find matrix rank according to parameter value

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I've been trying to solve this "simple" problem using the gaussian elimination method, but I don't get the right reduction steps to simplify the matrix and left a simple parameter term in the last row.

So I can't get the matrix rank according to the parameter value.

The matrix is:
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & a & a \\
 a & a & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & a & 1 & a \\
\end{pmatrix}

Just any ideas of what reduction steps should I use?, I may solve it using this method, instead of calculating the Det.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You won't be able to use determinants because the matrix is not square.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog - I assume he means it to be an augmented matrix, so he is only referring to taking the determinant of the first 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason you are finding this hard is because the solution does not depend on $a$. Letting $x = -1, y = 1, z = 1$, we see that the all three equations hold regardless of the value of $a$.

So if you were after a value of $a$ that would make this solvable, they all do.

If you were looking for the dependence of $x, y, z$ on $a$, they are all constant.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was looking for the different matrix ranks respect the possible values of "a". For example, reducing the matrix, we should arrive to a more simple matrix that will let us state something like: "if a = 1, the matrix rank equals 1, and for any other value of a, the matrix rank will be 2"

Comment: The steps for Gaussian elimination on this matrix are fairly obvious: $(R2 - a*R1 \to R2), (R3 - R1 \to R3)$. We see that Row 2 is now $0$ when $a^2 - 1 = 0$ and Row 3 is now $0$ when $a = 1$. Otherwise both rows are solvable. Ergo, the rank is 1 when $a = 1$, is 2 when $a = -1$, and is $3$ otherwise.

Comment: thank you so much paul, you are right.